# Why does role id == "13","0" evaluate to false when role id is set to "13","0"?

Tags: php, laravel

how can i make role id equals 2 value
I don't know what to do
When I use this code it doesn't work

```
@if($lead->role_id == '13','0')
```

Comment: `if($lead->role_id == '13' || $lead->role_id == '0')` Just like PHP

Comment: remove the `@` and read the error messages

Comment: Or `if ( in_array($lead->role_id, [0, 13]) )`

Comment: *"... role id is set to "13","0"?"* Please, show me how you've managed to set 2 values to a single variable

Comment: Maybe you had better show us the values that can be in `$lead->role_id`

Comment: @Cid this is likely inside a Blade template, in which case the `@if()` syntax is fine

Comment: @DannyXCII ah, possible, I don't know Blade, to me OP's code was pure PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if some records role ID is equal to one of several ID's, in a Blade template you can do the following:

```
@if(in_array($lead->role_id, [13, 0]))
    ...
@endif
```

It's unlikely that your ID's are going to be stored as strings, but if for some reason they are, you can just wrap the numbers in `'` or `"`.